# Firebase security rules returning permission denied when trying to write to database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am making an app that creates processes for teams to complete.  These processes have members who are admins who can write to them and then just regular users who can read them.  When a user creates a process for the first time, they are made an admin by default.  However whenever I try to create a process, I get "permission denied" from Firebase and I am unable to.  I have essentially the same rule for reading (just replacing the 'users' path with the 'admins' path) and I am able to read the processes just fine. Just not able to make them.  Any ideas why this is happening.

Here are the security rules for processes:

```
"processes": {
        "$processID": {
          ".read": "auth.uid != null && data.child('users/' + auth.uid).val() === true",
          ".write": "auth.uid != null && newData.child('admins/' + auth.uid).val() === true"
        }
      }
```

Here is the data structure for processes:

```
processes
 -KQ_j5Yt75GktE5pBRFS
   admins
      HESy7LE7JbeNyHKaGeyWRhNIuE83: true
   createdOn: "2016-09-01T04:00:00.000Z"
   description: "This is an example process"
   name: "Example Personal Process"
   tasks
   team: "-KQ_iwUmXsx0zasoPxT9"
   users
      HESy7LE7JbeNyHKaGeyWRhNIuE83: true
```

Here is the function where I create a process:

```
actions: {
        createProcess(processName, processDescription) {
        var teamId = this.controllerFor('processes/new').get('teamId');
        var self = this;
        console.log("team: "+teamId);
        let currentUser = this.get('user').get('currentUser');
        let team = this.get('store').peekRecord('team', teamId);
        let user = this.get('store').peekRecord('user', currentUser.id);
        console.log("user "+currentUser.id)
        let process = this.get('store').createRecord('process', {
            team: team,
            user: user,
            admin: user,
            name: processName,
            description: processDescription
        });
        user.get('processes').pushObject(process);
        user.get('processesLead').pushObject(process);
        team.get('processes').pushObject(process);
        console.log("about to save process");
        process.save().then(function () {
        console.log(process.admin.id);
        user.save();
        console.log("user saved");
        team.save();
        console.log("team saved");
    }).then(() => this.transitionTo('team', teamId));
       }
```

Here is part of my user model.

```
processes: DS.hasMany('process'),
  tasks: DS.hasMany('task'),
  processesLead: DS.hasMany('process', { inverse: 'admins' }),
  teamsLead: DS.hasMany('team', { inverse: 'admins' }),
  tasksLead: DS.hasMany('task', { inverse: 'admins' }),
  processMember: DS.hasMany('process', { inverse: 'members' }),
  teamMember: DS.hasMany('team', { inverse: 'members' }),
  taskMember: DS.hasMany('task', { inverse: 'members' })
```

Here is part of my process model:

```
 users: DS.hasMany('user'),   
    admins: DS.hasMany('user', { inverse: 'processesLead' }),
    members: DS.hasMany('user', { inverse: 'processMember' })
```

Comment: show the code, where you writing to DB

Comment: And for god's sake, replace date/time string with UNIX timestamp

Comment: Just added code.  @DimaRostopira

Comment: wait, which language it is? 0_o JS?

Comment: Yeah JS.  I'm using Ember as the framework. @DimaRostopira

Comment: sorry then, I'm mobile dev, can't help

Comment: Okay no problem, thanks anyway @DimaRostopira

Answer (score -1):

You have to seperate `data.child('users/' + auth.uid)`  into 2 different `.child()` statements. So something like this: `data.child('users').child(auth.uid)`.

Comment: So I just tried that and still have the same problem.  I am able to read the processes, but still can't write to them.  Any idea why? Does it have to do with the fact that I'm using newData for writing?